# Play framework with Google App Engine, will this destroy scalability?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web, playframework

Could I get some advice on what is the better way?
My questions regard Play framework, Google App Engine and web development.

So I am about to start writing a website which (the hope is) will be become quite popular and therefore will need to scale.  I have heard from more experienced developers that my system will not work (a play framework on a VPS backed by Mysql).  Apparently this just does not scale.  Especially if storing and searching through many 
It has been suggested that I use a system like Google App Engine (GAE) that handles all the scalability aspects.  However I am just starting to realise that this means a different mind set (Application Centric).

My main question is whether I should still use play framework?  The default way of using GAE is using plain Java servlets but I have found a plug in that allows play to interact with it.  I like working with play but I am worried that this will diminish all the benefits of GAE scalability rendering the effort in porting my application to GAE useless.

Can anyone give some advice?

Update - to further explain:
I was worried about using components that play framework provides such as sessions, cookies, etc.  I am assuming that these will not be scalable unless I use the GAE api directly?  I have heard that storing state like sessions is not very good and I should use the provided APIS.  Or does Play's plug in already handle this?
Also, 
Cheers

Comment: Explain *exactly* why you think using a framework like Play could possibly affect scalability. Otherwise its too broad. And no it wont affect it. Your choice of sql Will affect it.

Comment: @zigmandel. Basically I was worried about using Play's built in components for managing sessions, actors, etc.  I assumed that because I am using GAE I should use their APIs for that kind of stuff.  Does the play plug in link to their apis already?